# Spring Boot with Sqlite3 not able to autowire JPArepository interface

Tags: java, spring-boot, sqlite, spring-data-jpa

I am using the latest Spring Boot 2.1.3 version and Sqlite3 as DB.There is no error in compilation but Spring is not booting up throwing autowire exception when it is trying to autowire my JpaRepository bean.I have no clue why as I am doing exactly whats told.

Here is my pom.xml :

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.globomatics</groupId>
<artifactId>bike</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>bike</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zsoltfabok</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is my main class:

```
package com.globomatics.bike;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class BikeApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(BikeApplication.class, args);
        }

    }
```

BikeController:

package com.globomatics.bike.controllers;

```
   @RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/bikes")
public class BikesController {

    @Autowired
    private BikeRepository bikeRepository;


      @GetMapping public List<Bike> list(){ return bikeRepository.findAll(); }
```

My Entity class:

```
 package com.globomatics.bike.models;

@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer","handler"})
public class Bike {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String model;
    private String serialNumber;
    private BigDecimal purchasePrice;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy")
    private Date purchaseDate;
    private boolean contact;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }
    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
    public String getSerialNumber() {
        return serialNumber;
    }
    public void setSerialNumber(String serialNumber) {
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
    }
    public BigDecimal getPurchasePrice() {
        return purchasePrice;
    }
    public void setPurchasePrice(BigDecimal purchasePrice) {
        this.purchasePrice = purchasePrice;
    }
    public Date getPurchaseDate() {
        return purchaseDate;
    }
    public void setPurchaseDate(Date purchaseDate) {
        this.purchaseDate = purchaseDate;
    }
    public boolean isContact() {
        return contact;
    }
    public void setContact(boolean contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


}
```

And, finally here is the repository :

```
package com.globomatics.bike.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.globomatics.bike.models.Bike;

public interface BikeRepository extends JpaRepository<Bike, Long> {

}
```

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field bikeRepository in
>   com.globomatics.bike.controllers.BikesController required a bean of
>   type 'com.globomatics.bike.repositories.BikeRepository' that could not
>   be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>     - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.globomatics.bike.repositories.BikeRepository' in your
>   configuration.

Comment: Use `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` instead of only `spring-data-jpa`, replace that dependency. Also you might want to start with `--debug` or at least have a look at the logging because there probably is a stacktrace telling you why this failed. (Probably due to some DB setup).

Comment: Many thanks its working now, I missed this out ! :)